# Pandas Dataframe conditionally substituting multiple looked up values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update the values in multiple columns (a,b) in a dataframe, using values looked up from another dataframe, *iff* a in dataframe1 column is blank.

Here is an example setup:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Animal': ['Bear', 'Dog', 'Snake'],
    'Softness': [ 80,None, 2],
    'Other': ["o1", "", "o3"]
}).fillna('')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Animal2': ['Bear', 'Snake', 'Dog'],
    'Softness2': [ 70, 1, 100],
    'Other2': ["o4", "o5", "o6"]
})

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Resulting in:

```
df1:
  Animal Softness Other
0   Bear       80    o1
1    Dog
2  Snake        2    o3

df2:
  Animal2  Softness2 Other2
0    Bear         70     o4
1   Snake          1     o5
2     Dog        100     o6
```

I would like to conditionally replace values in df1's `Softness` and `Other` columns, with their counterparts in df2 only if `Softness` is blank in df1. Example result:

```
  Animal Softness Other
0   Bear       80    o1
1    Dog      100    o6
2  Snake        2    o3
```

I've been able to do just the one `Softness` column using where. But I'm at a loss as to how to do both (and am not sure about the efficiency consequences of the map lookup - the real dataset is obviously much larger and not animal softness related).

What are my options for accomplishing this (i'm not attached to numpy.where - it was just what I knew for my first attempt)? (Bonus q:) And what are the efficiency concerns with each?

```py
softness_lookup = df2.set_index('Animal2')['Softness2'].to_dict()
df1['Softness'] = np.where(df1['Softness'] == '', df1['Animal'].map(softness_lookup), df1['Softness'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
dict_softness = df2.set_index('Animal2')['Softness2'].to_dict()
dict_other = df2.set_index('Animal2')['Other2'].to_dict()
mask = df1['Softness'].eq('')
df1.loc[mask, 'Softness'] = df1.loc[mask, 'Animal'].map(dict_softness)
df1.loc[mask, 'Other'] = df1.loc[mask, 'Animal'].map(dict_other)
```

Comment: but i do not want to update `Other` unless `Softness` is empty. Even if Other is empty`. Suppose I could just change the condition in the second line though

Comment: Yes, you could just use the softness mask

Comment: Can confirm this works. Will wait on other suggestions to compare readibility/performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Merge is also an option:

```py
# Merge
merged = df1.merge(df2,
                   left_on='Animal',
                   right_on='Animal2')

# Mask
m = merged['Softness'].isnull()
# Update Values
merged.loc[m, ['Softness', 'Other']] = \
    merged.loc[m, ['Softness2', 'Other2']].to_numpy()
# Drop df2 columns
merged = merged.filter(regex=r'.*(?<!2)$')
print(merged)
```

Output:

```
  Animal  Softness Other
0   Bear      80.0    o1
1    Dog     100.0    o6
2  Snake       2.0    o3
```

Comment: Interesting. This is significantly faster for larger datasets than the dict lookup based solution.
dict:
[1000002 rows x 3 columns]
Elapsed: 7.9423911571502686
merge:
[1000002 rows x 3 columns]
Elapsed: 2.3292410373687744
(also I removed the df2 cols like this merged_df = merged_df.drop(df2.columns, axis=1))